# All 3 ways of moving to new page on click of button in the ionic navbar dont work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Ideally, all 3 methods ought to work. 
This codepen below shows all 3 methods well.

**[Correct and working CodePen Demo app](http://codepen.io/gregorypratt/pen/oJcHx)**

Currently, neither of the 3 methods work; the navbar just dissappears upon clicking the button (shows empty nav bar) while the core page remains the same main page.

Im not sure if its an code problem, ionic issue or just simply I should not transit to a new page from a navbar. The last one is too illogical to accept though.

Would any kind souls know where the issue lie and help me please?

**My core content code in index.html**

```
<body animation="slide-left-right-ios7">

        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light nav-title-slide-ios7"></ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**The button html I have (Note all 3 versions were tested seperately)**

```
    <ion-view ng-controller="NavCtrl"> 

     <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" ng-click="create('tab.newpost')"></button>
      <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" ui-sref="tab.newpost"></button>
      <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" href="/tab/newpost"></button>
     </ion-nav-buttons>

     <ion-content class>
        <!-- Rest of the content body here --> 
     </ion-content> 
    </ion-view>
```

**Code in nav.js mainly for the state.create method**

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $state, Post, Auth) {
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

    $scope.create = function(stateName) {
      /* $location.path('/tab/newpost'); */ 
      $state.go(stateName);  /* tried swapping stateName with 'tab.newpost' and func() */
    };
  });
```

**Code for app.js (Route file)**

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic','firebase']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('tab', {
          url: '/tab',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })

        .state('tab.posts', {
          url: '/posts',
          views: {
            'tab-posts': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
              controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

        .state('tab.newpost', {
          url: '/newpost',
          views: {
            'tab-newpost':{
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
              controller: 'NewCtrl'
            }
          }
        });

        /* + other states .... */

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth/login');
});
```

Comment: where are the tabs with the associated `<nav-view>` elements defined?

Comment: the tabs are in seperate html file called tabs.html, of which states are defined in the app.js (shown above as well).  If you are referring to the index.html, the lines are there to allow navbar template to appear on the pages and are currently empty at the moment. Its supposed to pick up whatevers in the other html files to render in the index.html file I guess, but theres no tests or error messages.

Comment: there are 3 pieces to the routing engine.  The first is the content which is to be displayed.  the second is the command to select which content to use.  the third is the container that the content is to be inserted into.  I suspect you are missing the container.

Comment: Hi @AndrewCounts HOw do I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

First method you used according to the your code look like this

```
ng-click="create('tab/newpost')"
```

It should be

```
ng-click="create('tab.newpost')"
```

Comment: Thanks @Seminda. Apologies for the typo. I tried this way too but error still there.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to modify states name so you can navigate between them

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ionic','firebase']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

        .state('tab', {
          url: '/tab',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })

        .state('tab.posts', {
          url: '/posts',
          views: {
            'tab-posts': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
              controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

        .state('tab.newpost', {
          url: '/newpost',
          views: {
            'tab-posts':{            /* the same name of the above state */
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
              controller: 'NewCtrl'
            }
          }
        });

        /* + other states .... */

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth/login');
});
```